# Add eventListeners to each element from a NodeList

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add eventListener Click to each element of a NodeList. I've tried the following

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName('productLnk')

function theTest (element,index,array){
 element.addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log('hello')
 })
}

test.forEach(theTest)
```

It returns test.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `NodeList` to `Array` for iterating using **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method. In ES6 use **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** method

```
Array.from(test).forEach(theTest)
```

or in older browser use **[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** with **[`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)** or **[`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**.

```
[].slice.call(test).forEach(theTest)
```

Comment: But more importantly, don't do it! Attach 1 event listener to the root of the list and distinguish between the sources from there.

Comment: @ZenMaster It depends on the usage. Sometimes your approach is not as optimal as adding independent listeners to each item.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Do tell.

Comment: @ZenMaster : who knows all the elements are in the same roots... that's just an assumption...

Comment: @PranavCBalan While theoretically you might be right (and even then - finding that root shouldn't be that complex), the example is `document.getElementsByClassName('productLnk')` ... So it is safe to assume that there is a list of products involved. There _is_ a common root.

Comment: @ZenMaster : if they are in multiple root elements.... why should want to make it that much complex ????

Comment: @PranavCBalan Because attaching multiple event handlers has an impact on performance?

Comment: @ZenMaster :  yes I know .. but we can't attach to the parent on all scenario ... in this particular case even we don't know the DOM structure